# confused on mysql transactions in php

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

if I use transactions, will it lock the tables and prevent it from making any changes by other users?

pseudo code:

```
 begin transaction
   issue a select query
   issue a update query
 end transaction
```

so, in between those two queries, is it possible to make some changes by another update statement or something which was issued from another page ?

or since the beginning of the transaction, will the tables used be locked ?

What is the difference between transaction and lock table? will a transaction implicitly lock the table ?

**Edit:**
This is what i want to do:

```
{
    // Check Table2 (posted messages)
    // If is_approved is FALSE for a given msg_id
    {
        // Set is_approved to TRUE
        // Update Table1 (member details) post_count_month++
        //     and post_count_lifetime++
    }
    // Else
    {
        // NOOP
    }
}
```

Above updation can be made by several users at the same time. Also, a single user(Admin) could delete a message(both accepted and not accepted message). So for deleting, the countmonth and countlifetime of the user who had posted that message(the one to be deleted) should be incremented and then message is deleted.

This is the two situation I am facing.

Comment: thank you Verbeia, for correcting my grammar mistakes

Comment: thank you Bracketworks, for correcting my pseudo code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transactions and table locking are different features that solve different problems. In your case you only seem to perform one write operation into the database, thus using a transaction will not provide any benefit unless you want to able to *undo* the update.

Have a look at the [SELECT ... FOR UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) statement.

**Update #1:**

Alright, here you are some code:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT member_id, is_approved
FROM posted_messages
WHERE msg_id=31416
FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE member_details
SET post_count_month=post_count_month+1, post_count_lifetime=post_count_lifetime+1
WHERE member_id=123;

UPDATE posted_messages
SET is_approved=TRUE
WHERE msg_id=31416;

COMMIT;
```

*(I'm not sure about how helpful it'll be, considering that I've invented all the queries. Understanding the code is always better than copying and pasting.)*

**Update #2:**

I've edited the sample code to surround the queries in a transaction. I said that transactions and table locking are different features and it's still true. However, the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` works inside a transaction. It's just an implementation detail.

> Locking of rows for update using SELECT FOR UPDATE only applies when
>   autocommit is disabled (either by beginning transaction with START
>   TRANSACTION or by setting autocommit to 0. If autocommit is enabled,
>   the rows matching the specification are not locked.

Comment: what i am doing is updating a counter field. so when a new message is submitted by the user, this message will be stored in a separate table. and when a mod or admin reviews it and accepts it, the counter field of the user table will be updated by incrementing it by 1.

but if the admin blocks or remove the message, then this counter field will be decremenented by 1. so, the counter field act as a container to store the count of messages that that each user submits.

Comment: so, there are two possibilites:
1. multiple moderators tries to accept the messages posted by the same user(so, the counter field will be incremented by 1 for each acceptance by the moderator)

2. admin might be deleting or blocking a message of a particular user where at the same time, some moderator might be accepting another message of that particular user.

Comment: Yup. This is called a "race condition". It has been widly researched and discussed. You can find millions of hits by googling it.

Comment: @VppMan - I insist: transactions will allow you to undo the complete set of queries but they won't help you with concurrent updates. Please follow the link in my answer and read about `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario thank you. I have update my first post and described my situation. Can you help me with code for first problem. And for second problem(related with admin deleting message), please give me guidance. I will code it. Do not consider that I am lazy. But i am very confused at the moment. A start on code may help me.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario thank you. I did not noticed that you had edited and posted code. I am not going to copy and paste the code. Trying to learn from it.
Please correct me if I am wrong, since post_messages table is selected FOR UPDATE, it will be locked until that table is updated(that is what the 3rd query is doing). Correct ?

Comment: @VppMan - MySQL will only lock the affected *rows* rather than the complete table. But tables won't be unlocked when they're UPDATEd. I've edited my answer to make the details clear.

Comment: "_But **tables** won't be unlocked when they're UPDATEd_" - you mean **rows**, right ?

Comment: @VppMan - Yep. Tables are only partially locked. It's explained in the documentation.

Comment: ok. thank you. And if i want to set the `post_count_month` field of all records in `member_details` at the end of month, i should use a query like this: `UPDATE member_details SET post_count_month = 0`
This will set all the records's `post_count_month` field value to 0. No need to use FOR UPDATE. Correct ? Because UPDATE statements like that already implements shared lock. Correct ?

Comment: @VppMan - SQL statements are supposed to be atomic.

Comment: that means what i said was correct. Isn't it ? (Some technical terms are confusing. So i request you to include a "yes" or "no" along with your answers :) ) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Transactions are designed to make database operations atomic (or non-divisible).

Imagine the problem you will have if you are doing an increment.

First you read the value as 1, then you add 1 to it to become 2, then you write 2 back to the database.

If at the point inbetween your adding 1 and writing back to the database, someone else does the same and read the value of 1, the maybe subtract 1, then write back as 0. One of the values will be lost. The end result will either be a 2, or a 0 cepending on the order the updates are applied.

(see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition for more info)

As for the locking of tables during transactions, It will depends on the database management system used.

For some, it will not lock the tables, but will raise an exception when the updates will cause discrepencies with the result. Forcing what is called a "automatic roll back".

For other dbms, they might implement it using locks.

Comment: thank you

so, if i use innodb (which i believe is the default one), does it support auto locking ?

still i'm not sure that i understood transactions completely.

the only use of transactions is to rollback if any problem occured. correct ?

Comment: For database transactions, you usually do not need to care how the dbms implements it. You just need to know that if he transaction is sucessful, your data will be consistant.

If you really need to know, you can look here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_serializable

Comment: sorry english is not my first language. 

you have helped me a lot by giving more details. but i only understood some of them.

please provide me a simple version(idea) that is easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it depends on the storage engine you use for  your tables. All sorts of weird things can happen with various mysql settings/storage engine options.

If for example you have InnoDB tables and allow dirty reads - It means other client can read Ghost Rows - which dont exist - are different etc

Comment: thank you. My host allows both myISAM and InnoDB. And from some comments and other articles, i found that innoDB is better and widely used and gives row-level locking and is default available in mysql. So i will use innoDB.

Comment: please help me. I am desperate :(

Comment: Sure thing - but what is your exact problem (I know sometimes its hard to describe when you arent sure of all the tech terms to use)

Comment: As I mentioned in the first post(edited entry), i need to know how to update those fields without causing problems(concurrency issues). I know basic sql querying and other things. But i do not know how to do the above mentioned updation using LOCKS and TRANSACTIONS. I had read articles and documents listed in above comments(by others). But it is tough to understand. SELECT USING SHARED LOCK document says something about updating counter(like in my issue). But it is not clear to how to use it.

Comment: OK - if you need to update a row in a table - mysql will take care of all the details for you regardless of engine etc. You are SAFE :-) - now if you need to change multiple row in multiple tables or same table - then you need to use transactions - then you need a transactional supported DB tables and define from a business point of view what your transaction is. A bad basic example is that I want to post 10 deposits to adrians account - the rule is I post all 10 or none - I cant post 5 a stop with an error because when I retry Adrian gets more money

Comment: so in my case, i should use a transaction and use SHARED LOCK inside it ? I am using PDO in PHP.